# Git branch and local changes

Tags: github, git-branch, branching-and-merging

Lets say I do a `git checkout -b my_new_branch`. Making some changes to my local files and after this I add all files with `git add.` and commit it and push. After this i realize that my branch is messed up and I want to delete it.

So Im going back to my master with `git checkout master` and delete the branch with `git branch -D my_new_branch`.

Will all local changes be reversed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you checkout the master branch, all of the changes that you made on `my_new_branch` will no longer be in your working directory. They will still be on your branch and on the server.

Once you delete `my_new_branch`, the ref to that branch will be deleted. The commits will still exist in your local repository until a garbage collection is run. The commits and branch will also still exist on the remote server.

Comment: Lets say i have a index.html and I change this file in a branch. Will there be 2 version of this file in my local working directory? Or will git upload the my_new_branch file and download the master index.html?

Comment: There will never be more than one version of a particular file in your working directory. When you checkout a new branch, git updates all of the files in your working directory to be the same as they are on that branch. Does that help? You might want to make a practice repo to try this stuff out on. Also, read the git book! http://git-scm.com/book